# Does reduced mass effect the size of the hydrogen atom?

Tags: hydrogen

According to various other answers on this site, most seem to feel that the Bohr Radius is the most accurate size of the hydrogen atom assuming this is defined as the radius where the electron is most often.  This would seem to be contradicted by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_radius which includes a section on reduced mass effects.  So which is correct, the Bohr Radius or the version with reduced mass?

Comment: The correction is small and therefore often ignored. There are also *other* corrections.

Comment: Do you have the complete calculation?

Comment: I don’t think it can be exactly calculated because all the higher-order quantum-field-theoretic effects are so complicated. But I think I’ve seen a calculation using the Dirac wavefunction. This would include relativistic effects and spin effects, but not things like vacuum polarization by virtual electron-positron pairs.

Comment: @Ghoster this is very interesting.

Comment: Yes. A century after quantum mechanics, I know of no truly exact solution even for “simple old hydrogen” taking all QFT effects into account, even one treating the proton as elementary. However, we can probably do theoretical calculations that are at least as accurate as experimental measurements.

Comment: @Ghoster this is quite shocking.  Has none attempted it?

Comment: I’m sure people have tried. Some quantum field theories *are* exactly solvable, but QED is apparently not one of them. Fortunately, perturbation theory seems to work well for getting accurate-but-approximate results that agree with experiments.

Comment: For helium and other atoms, we don’t even have an exact solution of the Schrodinger equation! But this doesn’t stop physicists from understanding atomic structure quite well.